# Django DeleteView not showing errors, but not deleting either

Tags: django, django-views, django-channels

I'm trying to create a one way `DeleteView` for a Django Channels messaging thread between 2 users.

I'm calling `DeleteView` with a form on the `ThreadView` page.

thread.html

```
<form action="{% url 'chat:thread_delete' thread.second %}" method='post'>
     {% csrf_token %}
     <button type='submit' class='btn btn-light'>
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt" style="color:royalblue">
        </i>
     </button>
</form>
```

The URL changes when I click the form button from

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/bob/
to 
http://127.0.0.1:8000/messages/bob/delete/
```

And there are no errors but nothing happens. The thread page just reloads, messages and all. It doesn't redirect to inbox as I've specified in the `success_url`.

Can someone help?

views.py

```
class InboxView(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):
    template_name = 'chat/inbox.html'
    context_object_name = 'threads'
    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user).exclude(chatmessage__isnull=True).order_by('-timestamp')
        # by_user(self.request.user)

class ThreadView(LoginRequiredMixin, FormMixin, DetailView):
    template_name = 'chat/thread.html'
    form_class = ComposeForm
    success_url = '#'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Thread.objects.by_user(self.request.user)

    def get_object(self):
        other_username  = self.kwargs.get("username")
        obj, created    = Thread.objects.get_or_new(self.request.user, other_username)
        if obj == None:
            raise Http404
        return obj

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = self.get_form()
        return context

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.user.is_authenticated:
            return HttpResponseForbidden()
        self.object = self.get_object()
        form = self.get_form()
        if form.is_valid():
            return self.form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        thread = self.get_object()
        user = self.request.user
        message = form.cleaned_data.get("message")
        ChatMessage.objects.create(user=user, thread=thread, message=message)
        return super().form_valid(form)

class ThreadDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Thread
    success_url = reverse_lazy('chat:inbox')
```

urls.py

```
  app_name = 'chat'
    urlpatterns = [
        path('', chat_views.InboxView.as_view(), name='inbox'),
        re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", chat_views.ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread'),
        re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)/delete/", chat_views.ThreadDeleteView.as_view(), name='thread_delete'),
    ]
```

models.py

```
class ThreadManager(models.Manager):
    def by_user(self, user):
        qlookup = Q(first=user) | Q(second=user)
        qlookup2 = Q(first=user) & Q(second=user)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup).exclude(qlookup2).distinct()
        return qs

    # method to grab the thread for the 2 users
    def get_or_new(self, user, other_username): # get_or_create
        username = user.username
        if username == other_username:
            print(other_username)
            return None, None
        # looks based off of either username
        qlookup1 = Q(first__username=username) & Q(second__username=other_username)
        qlookup2 = Q(first__username=other_username) & Q(second__username=username)
        qs = self.get_queryset().filter(qlookup1 | qlookup2).distinct()
        if qs.count() == 1:
            return qs.first(), False
        elif qs.count() > 1:
            return qs.order_by('timestamp').first(), False
        else:
            Klass = user.__class__
            user2 = Klass.objects.get(username=other_username)
            if user != user2:
                obj = self.model(
                        first=user,
                        second=user2
                    )
                obj.save()
                return obj, True
            return None, False

class Thread(models.Model):
    first        = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_first')
    second       = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='chat_thread_second')
    updated      = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp    = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects      = ThreadManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.id}'

    @property
    def room_group_name(self):
        return f'chat_{self.id}'

    def broadcast(self, msg=None):
        if msg is not None:
            broadcast_msg_to_chat(msg, group_name=self.room_group_name, user='admin')
            return True
        return False
```

Comment: can you show the **`Thread`** model?

Comment: how the `username` is related to the `Thread` model?

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: In your Thread delete view, you are passing a `username` url keyword argument (see you `urls.py`). Is there any relation between that `username` and the `Thread` instance you wanna detete?

Comment: Ah, I see now. The link to start a chat with someone is `"{% url 'chat:thread' profile.user %}"` so it takes the username in order to create the thread URL (`re_path(r"^(?P<username>[\w.@+-]+)", chat_views.ThreadView.as_view(), name='thread')`

Comment: But yes I see your point, perhaps the link would be the `first` or `second` fields in the thread model?

Comment: The delete view identifying the instance to be deleted by a `pk` keyword argument in the url (most of the time/by default).

Comment: As in I should change url to `pk:id` for the thread id?

Comment: yup. Where id/pk is the pk/id of the `Thread` instance to be deleted

Comment: Okay so I have `path('<int:pk>/delete/', chat_views.ThreadDeleteView.as_view(), name='thread_delete'),` and the form action is now `{% url 'chat:thread_delete' thread.id %}` I can't believe I didn't catch that haha, seriously thanks for your help. Last question, when I `POST` the form, I get `DoesNotExist at /messages/2/delete/` and it's not redirecting back to inbox, when I manually go back to inbox, the thread still exists.